# Ostream operator overload not working

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am having issues with the ostream operator overload. When I cout in my Main() it outputs

```
/   c"\progra"
```

Why it is outputting the file path and not the stream I created, I can not figure out. I am omitting the code that is not part of outputting the array. I am trying to loop through each element of the array and add it to a string that is in the end outputted via cout;

**Main.cpp**

```
Search test(20);
test.init_sorted();
cout << test;
```

**Search.cpp**

```
Search::Search(int size)
{
    array_size = size;
    numbers = new int[size];
}

void Search::init_sorted()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            srand(for_srand);
            numbers[i] = rand() % 5;
        }
        else {
            srand(for_srand);
            numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1] + rand() % 5;
        }           
    }


}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Search & s)
{
    string output;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.array_size; i++) {
        output += s.numbers[i] + " / ";
    }

    os << output;
    return os;

}
```

**Search.h**

```
class Search
{

private:
    int array_size;
    int *numbers; 
    int for_srand = 10;   

public:
    Search(int);
    ~Search();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Search& dt);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined behaviour. Due to pointer arithmetic,

```
    output += s.numbers[i] + " / ";
```

is the same as

```
    output += " / "[s.numbers[i]];
```

Also, it's not going to format any number:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.array_size; i++) {
    out << s.numbers[i] << " / ";
}
```

That being said, unless you know what you're doing, use standard containers and algorithms, e.g. `std::vector<int>` instead of `int*`.

Comment: I unfortunately am not able to use a vector... any help on what I need to change to make the pointer to the array work?

Comment: @BrandonTurpy You've read the rest of the answer, beside the remark about data management, right? Your initialization and use of the allocated memory is somewhat fine, but you're missing `~Search()` and therefore leak memory.

Comment: OK, I figured it out! Thanks, you were correct, I did not realize the for loop as changed in your response.. that is my bad! Thanks for your help!